# WordPress таксономии

Tags: wordpress

При изучении таксономий столкнулся с проблемой:
the_terms() выводит список ССЫЛОК на термины (элементы таксономии), относящиеся к указанному посту. Как мне сделать также, но чтобы не было ссылок?[image: Как должно выглядеть]

Comment: Может лучше get_tems() - поместить в переменную и вывести только названия без ссылок?

Answer (score 0):

Для получения терминов поста используйте `wp_get_post_terms`:

```
$terms = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'your-taxonomy-name' );

if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) {
    foreach( $terms as $term ) {
         echo $term->name;
    }
}
```